# How hash references are created uniquely each time in perl?

Tags: perl

> ```
> my %hash1 = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
> my %hash2 = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
>
> my $hash_ref1 = \%hash1;
> my $hash_ref2 = \%hash2;
> ```

how the perl compiler creates two distinct hash reference in the memory even the key value pairs are same for both hashes?

Comment: Allocate two different pieces of memory, store the same value in each -- they're still two different pieces of memory; pointers to them differ even though dereferencing those pointers have the same result. So why is this surprising?

Comment: perl is built using C. Learn C and you'll have a full grasp on memory allocation.

Comment: Why would the hash references be the same? Do you think Perl should automagically search all variables to see which values are equal and link the variables? Sounds pretty crazy to me.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply, `my` creates a new variable when executed.

Maybe you think `( ... )` creates the hash. It does not. The parens are simply there to change precedence, like in mathematics. `a => 1, b => 2, c => 3` simply puts 6 scalars on the stack, to be assigned to the hash created by `my`.

`my %h;` is analogous to `Hash h = new Hash();` in another language.

```perl
use Data::Printer;

my @a;                          # Creates an array.

for ( 1..3 ) {
   my %h = ( id => "x$_" );     # Creates a hash (each time).
   push @a, \%h;
}

p @a;
```

Output:

```
[
    [0] {
            id   "x1"
        },
    [1] {
            id   "x2"
        },
    [2] {
            id   "x3"
        }
]
```

Internally, Perl has a number of optimizations to avoid having to create and destroy so many variables. The above actually describes the behaviour you should be observing rather than what actually happens.

---

Internal details:

`my` actually creates the variable at compile time. When executed, it pushes a special instruction on the stack. When the scope is exited, this special instructions causes the variable to be cleared (in the same manner that `$s=undef;`, `@a=();` and `%h=();` would) rather than destroyed. If the reference count indicates the variable is still being used, a new scalar/array/hash is created instead. Yes, that means that `my` causes variables to be created on scope *exit*.

```perl
sub f { 
   # When compiled, creates a scalar.
   # When executed, stacks instruction to clear $x.
   my $x = shift;

   # After copying $x on the stack,
   # this simply clears $x instead of destroying it.
   return $x;
}

sub g { 
   # When compiled, creates a scalar.
   # When executed, stacks instruction to clear $y.
   my $y = shift;
          
   # After creating a reference to $y on the stack,
   # this creates a new scalar for $y since
   # that scalar is still being referenced.
   # The old scalar for $y will get destroyed
   # once all remaining references to it are released.
   return \$y;
}
```